# Parallelize dummy data generation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, faker

I would like to generate a dummy dataset composed of a fake first name and a last name for 40 milion records using multiple processor n cores.

Below is a single task loop that generates a first name and a last name and appends them to a list:

```py
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker

def fake_data_generation(records):
    fake = Faker(['en_US','en_GB'])
    
    person = []
    
    for i in range(records):
        first_name = fake.first_name()
        last_name = fake.last_name()
        person.append({"First_Name": first_name,
                       "Last_Name": last_name}
                     )
    return person
```

Output:

```py
for i in range(5):
    df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data_generation(i))

>>> df
  First_Name Last_Name
0      Colin   Stewart
1    Barbara      Rios
2     Victor     Green
3  Stephanie     Booth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `providers` directly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from faker.providers.person.en_US import Provider as us
from faker.providers.person.en_GB import Provider as gb

first_names = list(set(us.first_names).union(gb.first_names))
last_names = list(set(us.last_names).union(gb.last_names))

N = 40_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({'First_Name': np.random.choice(first_names, N),
                   'Last_Name': np.random.choice(last_names, N)})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         First_Name Last_Name
0             Kayla      Tran
1              Gary     Bates
2             Daisy   Leblanc
3           Tiffany     Ahmed
4            Kellie       May
...             ...       ...
39999995   Kristine   Collier
39999996      Joyce     Mccoy
39999997       Paul   Padilla
39999998      Tonya     Bevan
39999999      Julie    Bright

[40000000 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: On my computer, the dataframe is created in less than 7 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted the below that worked with me. I'd appreciate any reviews or modifications for better performance or reducing any unnecessary steps.

```py
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import pandas as pd
from faker import Faker
from itertools import chain

fake = Faker(['en_US','en_GB'])

def generate_names_df():
    names = []
    first_name = fake.first_name()
    last_name = fake.last_name()
    names.append({"First_Name": first_name,
                  "Last_Name": last_name}
                )
    return names

results = Parallel(n_jobs=15)(delayed(generate_names_df)() for i in range(40000000))
results_unlisted = list(chain(*results))
df = pd.DataFrame(results_unlisted)

>>> df.shape
(40000000, 2)
```